# SP2013: Intercept Modal Window to Set a Height

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog

I have a list webpart on a custom page, and I have the Open in Dialog enabled.

How would I go about intercepting the standard SP modal call in order to pass a height value? My modal window is way bigger than it needs to be!

thank you!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what is happening to understand the question easily ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find it, somehow had not found this thread previously:

[Increase width for form modal dialog](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150222/increase-width-for-form-modal-dialog)

I made a tweak to make it adjust height, not width. I also did not need the piece of CSS he adds separately. Not sure why.